# Excel VBA - how to skip to next iteration in a Do Until...Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to skip to the next iteration in my vba code, with the 'continue' statement. Its not working..

```
  Do Until IsEmpty(xlSheet.Cells(row, 1))
       row = row + 1
       If xlSheet.Cells(row, 2) = "Epic" Then
          Continue
       End If
       xlSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value = 5
  Loop
```

Any idea??
Thanks..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VBA does not have a `Continue` statement.  You can get around it by doing something like

```
Do Until IsEmpty(xlSheet.Cells(row + 1, 1))
   row = row + 1
   If xlSheet.Cells(row, 2) <> "Epic" Then
       xlSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value = 5
   End If
Loop
```

or

```
Do Until IsEmpty(xlSheet.Cells(row + 1, 1))
    row = row + 1
    If xlSheet.Cells(row, 2) = "Epic" Then
        GoTo ContinueDo
    End If
    xlSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value = 5
ContinueDo:
Loop
```

---

Note: In both versions I changed `IsEmpty(xlSheet.Cells(row, 1))` to `IsEmpty(xlSheet.Cells(row + 1, 1))` or else you will end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I posted an answer based on VB keyword. Label is a nice alternative.

Comment: @pav - Yeah, I've done that on several occasions - googled something using "VBA" as part of the search terms, found a reference in MSDN, read it, posted an answer, and not realised that the MSDN page had nothing to do with VBA at all.

Answer (score 1):

So this is another possibility that works for me. Just skip the unwanted lines...

```
Do Until IsEmpty(xlSheet.Cells(row, 1))
   row = row + 1
   Do while xlSheet.Cells(row, 2) = "Epic" 
      row = row + 1
   Loop
   xlSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value = 5
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

While Visual Basic has 3 continue statements for 3 different loops (`Continue While`, `Continue Do`, and `Continue For`), oddly Microsoft VBA does not use any of them.  You are going to have to restructure your loops and conditionals to go without.

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this due to vba have not any continue statement using the Goto statement use for errors.

```
Do Until IsEmpty(xlSheet.Cells(row, 1))
       row = row + 1
       If xlSheet.Cells(row, 2) = "Epic" Then
          GoTo Exitloop
       End If
       xlSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value = 5
ExitLoop:
  Loop
```